# Creating a Python function that opens a textfile, reads it, tokenizes it, and finally runs from the command line or as a module

Tags: python, nltk

I have been trying to learn Python for a while now. By chance, I happened across chapter 6 of the official tutorial through a Google search link pointing
[here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts).
When I learned, from that page, that functions were the heart of modules, and that modules could be called from the command line, I was all ears. Here's my first attempt at doing both, openbook.py

```
import nltk, re, pprint
from __future__ import division

def openbook(book):
    file = open(book)
    raw = file.read()
    tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)
    words = [w.lower() for w in text]
    vocab = sorted(set(words))
    return vocab
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    openbook(file(sys.argv[1]))
```

What I want is for this function to be importable as the module openbook, as well as for openbook.py to take a file from the command line and do all of those things to it.

When I run openbook.py from the command line, this happens:

```
gemeni@a:~/Projects-FinnegansWake$ python openbook.py vicocyclometer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openbook.py", line 23, in <module>
    openbook(file(sys.argv[1]))
  File "openbook.py", line 5, in openbook
    file = open(book)
```

When I try using it as a module, this happens:

```
>>> import openbook
>>> openbook('vicocyclometer')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

So, what can I do to fix this, and hopefully continue down the long winding path to enlightenment?

Comment: No need to import things that you're not using, e.g. `pprint`, `re` & `division`

Comment: no need to, but it makes things easier actually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Error executing openbook.py

For the first error, you are opening the file twice:

```
openbook(file(sys.argv[1]))
ph0 = open(book)
```

Calling both `file()` and `open()` is redundant. They both do the same thing. Pick one or the other: preferably `open()`.

> #### open(...)
>
> `open(name[, mode[, buffering]])` → file object
>
> Open a file using the file() type, returns a file object.  This is the
>       preferred way to open a file.

#### Error importing openbook module

For the second error, you need to add the module name:

```
>>> import openbook
>>> openbook.openbook('vicocyclometer')
```

Or import the `openbook()` function into the global namespace:

```
>>> from openbook import openbook
>>> openbook('vicocyclometer')
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. It worked when I just took out the if statement at the bottom. What I was trying to do was make the Python runnable as a command line script with optional arguments, as in chapter 6 of the Python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you need to fix:

1. `nltk.word_tokenize` will fail every time:

   - The function takes sentences as arguments. Make sure that you use `nltk.sent_tokenize` on the whole text first, so that things work correctly.
2. Files not being dealt with:

   - Only open the file once.
   - You're not closing the file once it's done. I recommend using Python's `with` statement to extract the text, as it closes things automatically: `with open(book) as raw: nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)` ...
3. Import the `openbook` function from the module, not just the module: `from openbook import openbook`.

Lastly, you could consider:

1. Adding things to the set with a generator expression, which will probably reduce the memory load: `set(w.lower() for w in text)`
2. Using `nltk.FreqDist` to generate a vocab & frequency distribution for you.

Comment: Thanks for all of this input. Answers like yours are hard to come by on SE sometimes. As for your fifth point, there's not much point in using FreqDist on a book in which single words appear more than once.

Comment: If you are just testing vocab, then no, the frequency distribution isn't required. It can be useful for further analysis though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from openbook import *
```

instead of

```
import openbook
```

OR:

```
import openbook
```

and then call it with

```
openbook.openbook("vicocyclometer")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your interactive session, you're getting that error because you need to `from openbook import openbook`. I can't tell what happened with the command line because the line with the error got snipped. It's probably that you tried to `open` a `file` object. Try just passing the string into the openbook function directly.